# How to convert dp to pixels and and use it to draw to canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying to convert dp to pixels. I'm using this method:

```
//Converts device pixels to regular pixels to draw
private float dpToPixel(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
    return px;
}
```

Then I try to get the dp from a variable in my dimen.xml file, like this:

```
int buttonWidth = (int) dpToPixel(R.dimen.buttonHeight);
```

Then I create a scaled bitmap with the width of the `buttonWidth` variable.
Then finally I draw it to the canvas. But when I try to run it, nothing is displayed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think there's either a typo in your question or you really don't load the value for the height - you are actually loading a number representing the id of the resource. It should have been:

```
int buttonWidth = (int) dpToPixel(getResorces().getDimension(R.dimen.buttonHeight));
```

But...you don't need to do the transformation yourself:

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.buttonHeight);
```

Answer (score 15):

```
public class DensityUtil {  
    /** 
     * dip to px
     */  
    public static int dip2px(Context context, float dpValue) {  
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;  
        return (int) (dpValue * scale + 0.5f);  
    }  

    /** 
     * px to dp
     */  
    public static int px2dip(Context context, float pxValue) {  
        final float scale =  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;  
        return (int) (pxValue / scale + 0.5f);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Converting dp to pixel

```
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer